# Prove that any element in $S_n$ can be written as a finite product of the following permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Prove that any element in $S_n$ can be written as a finite product of the following 
permutations:

$(a)\ (12),(13), . . . , (1n)$

$(b)\ (12),(23),...,(n−1,n)$

$(c)\ (12),(12\dots n)$.

I have no idea where to start. I know that the products from each category results an element of $S_n$, but no clue for the reverse. I think if some element is n-cycle it must be possible to write as products of transpositions in $(a)$ and depending on the cycle, just order in product varies.

Thank you for guidance.

Comment: can you produce $(2,3)$ from the permutations in part (a)? ask yourself which of the transpositions is likely to be relevant - do you think $(1,4)$ is likely to help?

Comment: You really should try harder to do these problems yourself before asking for help. For (a) note that $(1,j)(1,k)(1,j) = (j,k)$, so you can get any transposition from these permutations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Every permutation in $S_n$ can be written as the product of disjoint cycles. Every cycle of at least two-length can be written as the product of transpositions. Every transposition can be written as the product of $3$ (if $a\ne 1 \ne b$ in $(a,b)$) or $1$ (if otherwise) transposition(s) each containing one $1$. So, any element in $S_n$ can be written as a finite product of the $(12),(13),...,(1n)$, transpositions.

Answer (score 9):

Every permutation is a product of transpositions. Hence all you have to check is:

1. Any transposition $(k\,l)$ can be obtained as a product of transpositions of type (a).
2. Transpositions of type (a) can be obtained as a product of transpositions of type (b).
3. Transpositions of type (b) can be obtained as a product of permutations of type (c).

We'll use the fact that any two transpositions are conjugate by a transposition:

**(1)** is easy: $\,(k\,l)=(1\,k)(1\,l)(1\,k)$.

**(2)** is by induction on $k$: $(1\,2)$ is both of types (a) and (b). Suppose now $(1\,k)$ can be obtained from transpositions of type (b). Then $(1\,k)(k,\,k+1)(1\,k)=(1\,k+1)$ is likewise obtained from type (b).

**(3)** also by induction on $k$: let $\gamma=(1\,2\,\dots\,n)\,$. We have $\,(2\,3)= \gamma(1\,2)\,\gamma^{-1}$, and more generally: $\,(k\enspace k+1)=\gamma^{k-1}(1\,2)\,\gamma^{-(k-1)}$ for all $\,2\le k\le n-1$.

Comment: @Renze: Thank you so much for correcting  this typo.